# How do I create a link to a specific Spirit flight?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, hyperlink

I am creating a React App, and I want to create a link to a specific Spirit Flight on (www.spirit.com).It looks like spirit.com uses a javascript framework, so I cant use the html link to specifically hyperlink someone to a specific flight. How do I pass data to https://www.spirit.com/DPPCalendarMarket.aspx to get me to a specific flight ?

Comment: If they're loading the data into page via Ajax, you can't link directly to it. You'd have to sniff the Ajax URL and grab the response.